# button inside floating div cannot be clicked

Tags: css, html

I found that button inside a div cannot be clicked, if the div is set as "float". In my html, the two buttons "a" and "b" cannot be clicked. Do you have any idea?

```
<div id="titlepanel" style="height:65px; position:absolute; top:0px; left:0px; width:70%; overflow:auto; background-color:#b0e0e6;" > 
       wait
    </div> 

    <div id="subtitlepanel" style="height:65px; position:absolute; top:0px; left:0px; width:70%; visibility:hidden; background-color:#aaaaaa; " > 
       subtitle
    </div> 

   <div id="buttonpanel" style="height:65px; width:12%;  float:right; background-color:#bbbbbb;">

       <input type="button" value="a" id="a"  /> 
       <input type="button" value="b" id="b"   /> 

    </div>
```

Comment: well I'm able to click with above code http://jsbin.com/ecipub

Comment: i have same problem because of overlapping buttons.. added correct floating values now working

Answer (score 0):

Your code example is working for me too..

however at a guess I'd say there is an absolutely positioned div (not in the code above) "over the top" of your buttons

try adding `position: relative;` to `<div id="buttonpanel">` it may work on it's own if not try adding a `z-index` too

Answer (score 0):

By the looks of it `#subtitlepanel` is being overlaid on top of the buttons. Add a `z-index` to `#subtitlepanel` as suggested. This is also a common issue in IE.